# Arduino - matriz 8x8

Tags: matriz, arduino

eu estou com uma matriz de led 8x8 e um arduino uno e pretendo exibir algumas frases na matriz mas não achei de forma alguma a datasheet. A numeração é HS-2388BS. Existe outro meio de saber que linha e coluna corresponde ao acendimento de cada led?

Comment: Veja: http://category.alldatasheet.com/index.jsp?sSearchword=MATRIX%20BM-2388%20%20HS-23088

Comment: Sem sucesso amigo.

Comment: https://youtube.com/watch?v=AbyycYSOUE0 Veja os comentários do vídeo.